# How to delete event google calendar api with notification (PHP)

Tags: php, curl, google-api

This is my PHP code below.

I don't know how to set the `sendNotifications` parameter.

Googling this did not help me find a solution.

```
<?php
......

public function DeleteCalendarEvent($event_id, $calendar_id, $access_token) {
        $url_events = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' . $calendar_id . '/events/' . $event_id;

        $ch = curl_init();      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_events);     
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token, 'Content-Type: application/json'));
        $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if($http_code != 204) 
            throw new Exception('Error : Failed to delete event');
    }

......
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

"sendNotifications" is a query params. https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete

So you can simple add it to URL

> $url_events = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' . $calendar_id . '/events/' . $event_id.'?sendNotification=true';

Comment: thanks for replying my questing. The solution i was done before but still can't work. No email receive.

Comment: can't check right now. Try .'?sendNotification=1', .'/?sendNotification=1', .'/?sendNotification=True'